# Fluentd: Copy logs locally as well push it to loki

Tags: fluentd, grafana-loki

I am using fluentd for log aggregation. My use case is I want to collect logs and store them in a single file as a backup as well as push it to loki to view in grafana.

Following is the config file:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 10091
  bind 0.0.0.0
  format none
</source>


<filter *.**>
   @type record_transformer
   enable_ruby true
   remove_keys source,container_id, container_name , ts, tsNs
   <record>
    service ${tag_parts[1]}

#     message ${record["msg"] ? record["msg"] : record["message"] ? record["message"] : record["MESSAGE"]}
  </record>
</filter>

<match SERVER1.*>
@type copy
  <store>
        @type loki
        url "http://LOKI_IP:PORT"
        flush_interval 1s
        flush_at_shutdown true
        buffer_chunk_limit 1m
        extra_labels {"agent":"SERVER1"}
        <label>
                filename
        </label>
  </store>
        <store>
                @type file
                path /fluentd/Log/SERVER1.%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S.log
                <buffer time>
                        timekey 1h
                        timekey_use_utc true
                        timekey_wait 2s
                        flush_interval 1h
                </buffer>
        </store>
</match>

<match SERVER2.*>
@type copy
  <store>
        @type loki
        url "http://LOKI_IP:PORT"
        flush_interval 1s
        flush_at_shutdown true
        buffer_chunk_limit 1m
        extra_labels {"agent":"SERVER2"}
        <label>
                filename
        </label>
  </store>
        <store>
                @type file
                path /fluentd/Log/SERVER2.%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S.log
                <buffer time>
                        timekey 1h
                        timekey_use_utc true
                        timekey_wait 2s
                        flush_interval 1h
                </buffer>
        </store>
</match>
```

Here SERVER1 and SERVER2 are sending logs to fluentd. I tried collecting logs from both servers in single file by adding

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 10091
  bind 0.0.0.0
  format none
</source>


<filter *.**>
   @type record_transformer
   enable_ruby true
   remove_keys source,container_id, container_name , ts, tsNs
   <record>
    service ${tag_parts[1]}

#     message ${record["msg"] ? record["msg"] : record["message"] ? record["message"] : record["MESSAGE"]}
  </record>
</filter>

<match *.**>
@type copy
    <store>
        @type file
        path /fluentd/Log/access.%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S.log
        <buffer time>
            timekey 10s
            timekey_use_utc true
            timekey_wait 2s
            flush_interval 10s
        </buffer>
    </store>
</match>

<match SERVER1.*>
@type copy
  <store>
        @type loki
        url "http://LOKI_IP:PORT"
        flush_interval 1s
        flush_at_shutdown true
        buffer_chunk_limit 1m
        extra_labels {"agent":"SERVER1"}
        <label>
                filename
        </label>
  </store>
</match>

<match SERVER2.*>
@type copy
  <store>
        @type loki
        url "http://LOKI_IP:PORT"
        flush_interval 1s
        flush_at_shutdown true
        buffer_chunk_limit 1m
        extra_labels {"agent":"SERVER2"}
        <label>
                filename
        </label>
  </store>
</match>
```

But with this, I am not able to see the latest logs in loki/grafana. Somehow it is only saving it locally and not sending it to loki.

So it's like **SAVE IT LOCALLY** or **PUSH IT TO LOKI**. I want both of these functionalities to have a single JSON file to have logs from both servers instead of different files from different servers. Can anyone help me out if it's possible at all?

Comment: You need to combine output targets under one [copy](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/copy) section.

Comment: Also, you need to revise the [match](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#2.-match-tell-fluentd-what-to-do) sections if there are multiple ones. The config file is processed as it's written from start to end. The sequence of match sections should be from specific to general e.g. `a`, `b`, `*`. The `a` events will be processed first, then `b` and then the rest `*`. But, if the sequence is reversed e.g. `*`, `a`, `b`, all the events will be processed by the first match i.e. `*`. The rest will be ignored. See: https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#note-on-match-order.